# AngularJS - Unit tests on Controller that uses moment.js

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, momentjs

I'm trying to make unit tests for a controller that uses moment.js to handle three dates of a week. My testing framework is jasmine and my AngularJS version is v1.3.15

Basically I have an init() function that sets them and I want to check if all of them are properly set in the controller.

```
var myController = this;

myController.init = function () {
    myController.currentDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    myController.startOfWeek = moment(currentDate).startOf('week').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    myController.endOfWeek = moment(currentDate).endOf('week').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
};
```

At this point I'm not sure if this approach is correct and/or if I should test this stuff here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2 things that i see regarding the code itself, `moment(new Date())` and `moment()` are the same. and i suppose you meant `myController.endOfWeek = moment(currentDate).endOf('week').format('DD-MM-YYYY');`

Comment: I'd also remove the 'currentDate' arg, as it's not safe according to [this](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407) , and actually gave me false results when tried it. just use `moment().startOf('week')...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass `currentDate` back in to the moment creation function.  Doing so will invoke parsing, will fall back to the browser's implementation (giving you a deprecation warning), and will fail if the browser's locale is not the same as the one you formatted.

Either just call `moment()` each time:

```
myController.currentDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
myController.startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
myController.endOfWeek = moment().endOf('week').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Or if you like you can capture the current time just once, then clone that moment for each function.

```
var now = moment();
myController.currentDate = now.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
myController.startOfWeek = moment(now).startOf('week').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
myController.endOfWeek = moment(now).endOf('week').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Passing a moment to the moment creation function will clone it, preventing `startOf` and `endOf` from mutating the original value.

Comment: Thanks! The last choice sounds fine to me.

Comment: About the unit testing part (please let me know if I should make a new post): I need to use the now variable as a pivot to update the rest of the dates, so I want to make a test to check if the now variable has changed when I call addWeek function. 

        MyController.now = moment('2015-05-18');
        MyController.addWeek();
        expect(MyController.now).toEqual(moment('2015-05-25'));

¿Is this the right way to test this functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're after, but it sounds like perhaps you want `currentDate`, `startOfWeek`, and `endOfWeek` to be *functions* based on the value of `now`?

Comment: Exactly. I have a "pivot" date and I need the startOfWeek, endOfWeek and currentDate values.